# Trigger Windows application from .Net MVC Based Web Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-scraping, desktop-application, scanning

I am planing to implement one .Net MVC based web application to handle scanning functionalities in Web. I did some research but i couldn't find any easy way to handle it from the web other than some expensive tools like kofax, scanner.js.., I already have a desktop application which will handle my scaning needs but now i need to handle it throw web.

Is there any possibility to invoke a desktop application from the web and handle scanning from the desktop application and store files in some common folder and upload files from that folder. I am looking for some help from the people who know about such kind of processing..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think silver light is good option for you

please refer this link for more information

http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/14/scanning-an-image-from-silverlight-4-using-wia-automation

Comment: I am looking for some option in MVC/jQuery itself